# checking for refresh in -lncurses..no checking for refresh in -lcurses no configure: error: *** Missing development libraries for ncurses in cygwin

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line-interface, amazon-elb

checking for refresh in -lncurses... no
checking for refresh in -lcurses... no
configure: error: *** Missing development libraries for ncurses

in windows local laptop

configure: error: *** Missing development libraries for ncurses